# Transaction unconfirmed over 30 hours!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I've bought bitcoin through bitcoin ATM machine several times, and this time was different that the transaction has unconfirmed for over 30 hours, usually transactions through the bitcoin ATM machine was just few minutes.

Can you guys please me and have a look at the transaction ID?Thanks!

https://blockchain.info/tx/41d3d5b80a912a566c5f842dc4e945f40c8b99291f1bf9e777616673dc7186a8

Answer (score -2):

brother - 
you are transacting almost SIX BTCS with a measly fee of .0002

THAT is why its taking such a long time and will continue to take a long time

Comment: The amount transacted is irrelevant to the transaction fee; the fee is only considered relative to the size of the transaction in bytes.

Comment: ino its the bytes that determine it. im talking from a miners pov...i obv shouldve been more clear